# Possible error in Rudin's Dedekind Cuts - Step 4

Tags: real-analysis

I am wondering about the following paragraph of the step 4 in Rudin's construction of Dedekind Cuts. The book is *Principles of Mathematical Analysis, 3rd edition* page 19. Specifically the author states that: *We have proved that $\beta \in R$. If $r \in \alpha$ and $s \in \beta$, then $-s \notin \alpha$, hence $r < -s, s + r < 0.$*

What I don't understand is that how come $-s$ does not necessarily belong to $\alpha$ if $s$ belongs to $\beta$? The construction for $\beta$ is that *Let $\beta$ be the set of all $p$ with the following property: There exists $r > 0$ such that $-p - r \notin \alpha$*. Therefore if $s \in \beta$ we know that $-s - \epsilon \notin \alpha$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. But this does not necessarily mean that $-s\notin \alpha$.

Comment: If $-s \in \alpha$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have that $-s -\epsilon < -s$ hence is in $\alpha$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Rushy Could you expand why we arrive at a contradiction?

Comment: because we assumed that $s$ is in $\beta$, there must be some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $-s -\epsilon \notin \alpha$. However if $-s \in \alpha$ this is impossible, so $-s$ can't be in $\alpha$.